# What does non - testable mean in this code example?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing

I need to analyze a code after playing a code and see if I have full coverage. Some part of the report is shown below:

```
    game->errorCode = ERROR_NO_MEMORY;                      
    #pragma RVS justification( "COV_STATEMENTS", "not testable");                       
}                       
else {                      
    /* Initialize platform */       
    game->errorCode = platformInit(game);
    if (game->errorCode == ERROR_NONE) {            
        /* If platform was correctly initialized, start the game */     
        startGame(game);        
    } else {                
        #pragma RVS justification( "COV_MCDC", "1:game->errorCode == ERROR_NONE", "not testable");
        #pragma RVS justification( "COV_DECISIONS", "not testable");                
    }
```

What does it mean when they say "not testable"? Is it a part of code that cannot be covered? And if so why?

Answer (score 0):

The term non-testable is used since, from the point of view of correctness testing, if one cannot decide whether or not the output is correct or must expend some extraordinary amount of time to do so, there is nothing to be gained by performing the test.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case "not testable" is used to tell a coverage analysis tool (RVS) that a certain piece of code shall not be taken into consideration in the coverage report.

From looking at the code I would say that this code definitely looks testable - it requires that the test has control over what `platformInit` returns (whether it makes more sense to test this in unit-testing or in integration testing would be a different question).  Consequently, the statement about the respective branches being "not testable" is wrong - but the intent here is not to give a true statement about testability, the intent is that although that branch is not covered by the respective tests, it shall not negatively influence the results in the coverage report.